# How to return a two dimensional array from C++ function to Python using boost python numeric array?

Tags: python, c++, arrays, boost, numeric

I am learning Boost Python interface especially on exposing the C++ function to Python. Now I have a problem on how to return a two dimensional array of C++ function to python side. For example, we have the following C++ code:

```
int** multiply(int** a, int m, int n){
  for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
      a[i][j] *= 2;
    }
  }
  return a;
}
```

I know there is a way to return the two dimensional array to Python using `ctypes`. But my problem is how to use the `boost::python::numeric::array` 
to do this, or if there are any other solutions without using the third-party libraries. I really appreciate if anyone can help me.